# Execute a task at method level with added grantedauthority(role) in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak, activiti

I have a spring project that uses keycloak for authentication, I also use activiti process engine. I found out that in order to start a process the current logged-in user must have a role ACTIVITI_USER. Intially it suffices to add this to the roles in keycloak and have all users have the role, but later found out I only ever needed this role for starting off a process. So what I would now prefer to do is find a way to include the role ACTIVITI_USER to the current logged in user only within the context of the method alone and the role would disappear after the method is executed. I have explored using the RunAsManager on GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration but I keep getting access denied exception

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AbstractAccessDecisionManager.checkAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions(AbstractAccessDecisionManager.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)

Here is how I configured my run as manager

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class RunAsSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected RunAsManager runAsManager() {
        RunAsManagerImpl runAsManager = new RunAsManagerImpl();
        runAsManager.setKey("MyRunAsKey");
        return runAsManager;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(runAsAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider runAsAuthenticationProvider() {
        RunAsImplAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new RunAsImplAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setKey("MyRunAsKey");
        return authProvider;
    }
}
```

and here is how I am using it on the method

```
@Secured({"RUN_AS_ACTIVITI_USER"})
public String startProcess() {
   // ...
}
```

Help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal. It sounds as if everyone that is authenticated is allowed to execute the method? If so, you might consider using `@PreAuthorize("authenticated")` which allows any authenticated user to invoke the method.

Comment: The goal is to temporary give users a particular role required to do activiti related tasks (ROLE_ACTIVITI_USER) and have that role taken away after the task is executed